# Using set pixel size and percentage together

Tags: html, css

I am styling a new page where they want a responsive design, but the menu up to mobile size is to be a set pixel width.  My question is how can i have a menu at set pixel width but have the rest of the page go out to the max possible % width.

Opps sorry forgot web address : http://adlantic.ie/responsive/

This is the css that I have so far :

```
.side-menu {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    border: 5px #E5E4E4 solid;
    font-size:12px;
}

.page-content {
    border: 5px #E5E4E4 solid;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:250px;

}
```

thanks

Comment: Can you provide us an example so we can see and figure out what you mean? Like a link to an active page, or designs?

Comment: Add a min-width to your menu with pixels. So it will be the minimum width the menu can take in any device size.

Comment: The relevant code should be included in the question itself. Links to external pages don't help neither now, nor in the future, when other people might refer to your question looking for answers to a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question in my opinion would be media queries. Then based on the viewport size you could add different css styles to match width of window thus allowing % and set pixels to be used on same element at different sizes. Example:`@media screen and (max-width:480px){.menu{width:100%;}}    @media screen and (max-width:1084px){.menu{width:200px;}}`